# As it is necessary to simplify the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code for mega dropdown menu on click. It works fine but code is Substandard, wrong. Is it possible to simplify it as anything? Here i writed the same action code for others

Look at the code:

```
$('.main-nav .first').click(function () {
    $('.drop-down-container').toggleClass('visible');
});
$('.main-nav .sec').click(function () {
    $('.drop-down-container-sec').toggleClass('visible')
});
$('.main-nav .rd').click(function () {
    $('.drop-down-container-rd').toggleClass('visible');
});
$('.main-nav .fth').click(function () {
    $('.drop-down-container-fth').toggleClass('visible');
});
$('.main-nav .fvth').click(function () {
    $('.drop-down-container-fvth').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item sec "><a href="#">JAMOA VA O`QITUVCHILARGA<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    <div class="drop-down-container-sec d-n" style="margin-left: -13em;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left " style="height: 510px;">
                <h4 style="color: white">Tezkor menyu</h4>
                <ul class="list-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Dars ishlanmalari</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ilg`or texnologiyalar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tajriba sinovlari</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kasaba uyushmamiz</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Moddiy-texnika bazamiz</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Davlat dasturlari ijrosi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Me`yoriy hujjatlar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Maktab konsepsiyasi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ustozlarimiz</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Maktab rahbariyati</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kadrlar salohiyati</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hisobot o`rnida</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Doimiy komissiyalar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Homiylarimiz</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hamkorlik</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ijodkor o`qituvchilar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Yilning eng yaxshi fan o`qituvchisi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Attestasiya materiallari</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">O`quv rejalari</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="all">
                    <a href="#" class="bottom-button">Umumiy yig'inda</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 right">
                <li class="nav-item rd "><a href="#">MAKTAB VA TA`LIM<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="drop-down-container-rd d-n" style="margin-left: -28em">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left">
                                <h4 style="color: white">Elektron kutubxona</h4>
                                <ul class="list-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Bitiruvchilar vinetkalari</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Maktab Nizomi</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Maktabimiz pasporti</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Ichki tartib-qoidalar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Ona-vatan madhi</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Alifbe bayramlari</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">To`garaklarimiz</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">"Bilimlar bellashuvi" akademiya klublari</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fotoalbom</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Videolavhalar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Tibbiy xizmat</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Ogohlik va xavfsizlik</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <p class="all">
                                    <a href="#" class="bottom-button">Barcha darsliklar</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 right">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <h5><a href="#">Imtihonlar jadvali</a></h5>
                                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 12px">Diqqat, diqqat, diqqat! Imtihon-2017. Sinovga puxta tayyorlaning!</p>
                                        <p class="button_red_small"><a href="#" style="color: #fff">Batafsil</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <h5><a href="#">
                                                Imtihonlar jadvali
                                            </a></h5>
                                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 12px">Diqqat, diqqat, diqqat! Imtihon-2017. Sinovga puxta tayyorlaning!</p>
                                        <p class="button_red_small"><a href="#" style="color: #fff">Batafsil</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <h5><a href="#">Imtihonlar jadvali</a></h5>
                                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 12px">Diqqat, diqqat, diqqat! Imtihon-2017. Sinovga puxta tayyorlaning!</p>
                                        <p class="button_red_small"><a href="#" style="color: #fff">Batafsil</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <h5><a href="#">
                                                Imtihonlar jadvali
                                            </a></h5>
                                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 12px">Diqqat, diqqat, diqqat! Imtihon-2017. Sinovga puxta tayyorlaning!</p>
                                        <p class="button_red_small"><a href="#" style="color: #fff">Batafsil</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <h5><a href="#">Imtihonlar jadvali</a></h5>
                                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 12px">Diqqat, diqqat, diqqat! Imtihon-2017. Sinovga puxta tayyorlaning!</p>
                                        <p class="button_red_small"><a href="#" style="color: #fff">Batafsil</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <h5><a href="#">Imtihonlar jadvali</a></h5>
                                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 12px">Diqqat, diqqat, diqqat! Imtihon-2017. Sinovga puxta tayyorlaning!</p>
                                        <p class="button_red_small"><a href="#" style="color: #fff">Batafsil</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

So dropdown menu is huge
Guys if it possible to Simplify and fix this code please help me! I just hate that kind of code.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but we'd need to see your HTML in order to help you effectively

Comment: ok i will add my html

Comment: i don't think your code is really wrong. It is more readable than a generic solution, and a generic solution would probably bring more operations made overall. EDIT: unless tou have hundreds of those, maybe

Comment: I prefer to write generic code

Comment: @Aziz I can't find any element with the class `main-nav` in your code

Comment: I prefer to adapt to the situation, too much generalization can be a loss of time overall, if not needed by your code. And most of the time, performance and readability are stronger than shortest code imo

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen main-nav + next class! Main nav is a block

Comment: @Aziz Without your full relevant html code, we can only give you a guess, can't guaranty that it works in your code. But take a look at the answers below

Answer (score 0):

Well, your HTML code does not contain any element with the class `main-nav`. But you can short your code down to something like the following.

```
$('.main-nav .first, .main-nav .sec, .main-nav .rd, .main-nav .fth, .main-nav .fvth').click(function() {
  var s = $(this).attr("class") == "first" ? "" : "-" + $(this).attr("class")
  console.log('.drop-down-container' + s)
  $('.drop-down-container' + s).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```js
$('.main-nav .first, .main-nav .sec, .main-nav .rd, .main-nav .fth, .main-nav .fvth').click(function() {
  var s = $(this).attr("class") == "first" ? "" : "-" + $(this).attr("class")
  console.log('.drop-down-container' + s)
  $('.drop-down-container' + s).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-nav">
  <div class="first">first
  </div>
  <div class="sec">sec
  </div>
  <div class="rd">rd
  </div>
  <div class="fth">fth
  </div>
  <div class="fvth">fvth
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like the following.

```
const array = ['first', 'sec', 'rd', 'fth', 'fvth'];
array.forEach(x => {
  $(`.main-nav .${x}`).click(() => $(`.drop-down-container${x === 'first' ? '' : '-'+x}`).toggleClass('visible') );
});
```

it will iterate the array and add the click function for `.main-val .YourClass` that will toggle the class for `.drop-down-container-YourClass`

Comment: This is wrong - check first click handler - there is no `$('.drop-down-container-first')` element

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Updated

Answer (score 0):

Let me simplify your code. Instead of handling each and every block separately with individual class names, change them to have common class names. Now you can easily do the toggling with any number of elements.

```js
$('.nav-item .dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.nav-item').find('.drop-down-container').toggle('slow');
  $('.navigation-tabs .dropdown-toggle').not(this).closest('.nav-item').find('.drop-down-container').hide('slow');
});
```

```css
.drop-down-container {display: none;}
.navigation-tabs {padding: 0;}
.nav-item {display: block; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;}
.nav-item a {display: block; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navigation-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
      JAMOA VA O`QITUVCHILARGA<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="drop-down-container">First container</div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
      MAKTAB VA TA`LIM<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="drop-down-container">Second container</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```